# sqlsrv_get_field not returning ID

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have a problem where I am trying to obtain the primary key(VisitID) of the last inserted row.

Whenever the query is run the DB is updated but the sqlsrv_get_field never returns the VisitID. Should I be using *sqlsrv_query* rather than *sqlsrv_prepare* or is there something I am totally missing?

```
$addvisitquery = "
        INSERT INTO blah;
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS VisitID";

    $addVisit = sqlsrv_prepare($connect,$addvisitquery);

    if( sqlsrv_execute($addVisit))
        {
          echo "Statement executed.\n <br />";
          echo "Number of rows updated:".sqlsrv_rows_affected($addVisit)." <br />";
          sqlsrv_next_result($addVisit)." <br />";
          sqlsrv_fetch($addVisit);

          echo "Returned VisitID:".sqlsrv_get_field($addVisit, 0)." <br />";

          sqlsrv_commit($connect);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `<br />` next to the function `sqlsrv_next_result($addVisit)`? That line doesn't have print or echo command so, I guess it prevents that function executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickhodge/archive/2008/09/23/sql-server-driver-for-php-last-inserted-row-id.aspx

Quite simply, Ensure your SQL statement has the following to return the last inserted row:

```
 ; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Create a php function:

```
function lastInsertId($queryID) {
        sqlsrv_next_result($queryID);
        sqlsrv_fetch($queryID);
        return sqlsrv_get_field($queryID, 0);
    }
```

Then add this line to to query the function :

```
echo "The last inserted row ID is ".lastInsertId($addVisit);
```

Comment: What's the relevant difference with your original code? At first sight they look pretty similar :-?